# Kafka Multiple Topic Input tranformation to Multiple Output Topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Hi i am new new to Kafka/java and am trying to implement an app where i read in from topics 0-9, transform each message i read in from these topics then produce them to topics New0-9. Between consuming and producing i need to alter the message, i am attempting to use flatMapValues as i only want to alter the value however im not sure how to set it up. I have implemented my transform function later in my class, i just haven't been able to understand the documentation on how the syntax for kafka streams works. If i wish to change

I currently have,

```
   final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
   
   KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream("0");
   source.flatMapValues(value -> MyTransform(value)).to("New0");
   final Topology topology = builder.build();
   final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);

   public String MyTransform(String initial){
   ....
   }
```

[Current error I don't really understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvlUo.png)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: You need to show your transform function. As the error says, flatMap needs to return an iterable type. If you simply want to modify one record to one output, you'd use mapValues

Comment: Thank you, i solved the issue. It was to do with the type of function and return needing to be Iterable.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own post down below